# Visual Studio: How to create customized summary tag for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I searched around web but didn't get any hint regarding how can we modify summary tag that gets generated in Visual Studio when typing ///. Is it possible at all? In my ASP.NET MVC C# project, I want to include "author" attribute in summary. If you have any resources describing how this can be achieved, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity ; why would you want to define authors down to the level of properties or methods? (or are you only looking to generate this for classes?) on a sidenote, decent version control like GIT or SVN can also tackle the "who wrote this?" question by running a so called "blame"

Comment: I want to generate this for classes as well as methods. Yeah, version control can indicate "author" but the project which I work in follows this particular pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**[Microsoft Visual Studio]** ❌

I don't understand why VS shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi2xu.png), even though the tags and their description are not displayed on the Method...

Even after several attempts, I unfortunately haven't found a solution to your problem. There might be a specific plugin that solves your problem.

**[JetBrains Rider]**. ✅

Here is how to display custom [documentation tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFRFc.png).

Here is what the [documentation popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8GGW.png) of Rider shows.

You can create as many description tags as you want, and give them any name you want, from the time you respect the writing model.

```
/// <name> 
/// description
/// </name>
```